# R: mapply with parameters as vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, mapply

**Background:**
I want to create additional column in `data.table` using `mapply` function. This column is designed to be calculated by function with variable structure and variable number of parameters, because of that I pass in `mapply` function definition as parsed character string.

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(x1 = c(1,2,3,4), x2 = c(3,4,5,2), x3 = c(3,4,5,2))
body <- "(x1 + x2) * x3"
args <- "x1, x2, x3"
fla = eval(parse(text = paste('f <- function(', args, ') { return(' , body , ')}', sep='')))
res_dt = dt[, k := mapply(fla, x1, x2, x3)]
```

This part of code returns following expected result:

> res_dt

```
   x1 x2 x3  k
1:  1  3  3 12
2:  2  4  4 24
3:  3  5  5 40
4:  4  2  2 12
```

But the formula for other columns that will be transformed can have other number of parameters, because of that I need to pass parameters in my function as vector.
But when I'm trying to do this as described bellow:

```
p = c('x1','x2','x3')
res_dt = dt[, k_fin := mapply(fla, p)]
```

I receive the following error:

```
> res_dt = dt[, k_fin := mapply(fla, p)]
Error in (function (x1, x2, x3)  : 
  argument "x2" is missing, with no default
```

**My question is:**
How can I pass vector with arguments in my function to make it work ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `do.call(fun, list(args))`

Comment: > res_dt = dt[, k_fin := do.call(fla, list(p))]
Error in (function (x1, x2, x3)  : 
  argument "x2" is missing, with no default

Comment: @Ryan, I need these parameters to be recognized as columns of data.table, it seems that approach with do.call doesn't work. However I'm not focused on data.table - mb there is a better solution via dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this approach might be helpful:

short answer:

```
p = c("fla", 'x1','x2','x3') #provide all arguments in a vector
res_dt = dt[, k_fin := do.call(mapply, as.list(get(p)))] #get objects named in p and convert them to a list, and provide that list as arguments to mapply
```

reproducible:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(x1 = c(1,2,3,4), x2 = c(3,4,5,2), x3 = c(3,4,5,2))
body <- "(x1 + x2) * x3"
args <- "x1, x2, x3"
fla = eval(parse(text = paste('f <- function(', args, ') { return(' , body , ')}', sep='')))
p = c("fla", 'x1','x2','x3')
res_dt = dt[, k_fin := do.call(mapply, as.list(get(p)))]
#output
   x1 x2 x3 k_fin
1:  1  3  3    12
2:  2  4  4    24
3:  3  5  5    40
4:  4  2  2    12
```

Comment: thank you very much!) That's the solution I was looking for!)